# Spark: driver logs showing "thread spilling sort data to disk"

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark

Could somebody help me understand what could be the possible reasons for the below lines coming in spark job logs.

> 2018-06-11T05:35:46,181 - INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task
>   328:Logging$class@54] - TID 328 waiting for at least 1/2N of on-heap
>   execution pool to be free 2018-06-11T05:35:46,182 - INFO  [Executor
>   task launch worker for task 329:UnsafeExternalSorter@202] - Thread 151
>   spilling sort data of 50.0 MB to disk (20  times so far)
>
> 2018-06-11T05:35:46,188 - INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task
>   322:UnsafeExternalSorter@202] - Thread 176 spilling sort data of 33.0
>   MB to disk (27  times so far)

Spark program working:

1. query the database, cache the whole table(2GB is cached)
2. select records sequentially for a country out of 3(Denmark, India, NewZealand)
3. break the dataframe in 500 pieces and pass it to a map function which creates the json of a set of records in a piece and send it to search server
4. map is being applied on parallel collection(Vector) to execute the parallel processing and we could send in parallel to search server for indexing.

I am newbie in Spark, so please help me to understand which part of configuration should I look to stop this spilling. Spark version is 2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

- Based on the log, you sort the data.
- During the sort **there is not enough memory** to store auxiliary data structures for shuffle in memory.
- Therefore Spark spills data to disk.

Comment: I am not doing sort in sql queries when I am fetching the data from cached table for a particular country e.g. NewZealand

Comment: after increasing the driver & worker memory I am able to see the reduced number of such warning.

Answer (score 0):

This log means there isn't enough memory for task computing, and exchange data to disk, it's expensive operation. 
When you find this log in one or few executor tasks, it indicates there exists data skew, you may need to find skew key data and preprocess it.

Comment: why does this suggest data skew? We could have even distribution, but still too much data to fit in executor memory.